# What does the compare function in F# do

Tags: f#

I was reading through the F# documentation and came across the [`compare`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-core-operators.html#compare) function. The examples in the docs do not really make it clear what the function does. I also tried it with a few inputs, but couldn't find a clear pattern.

When comparing lists the values are either -1, 0 or 1.

```ml
> compare [1;2;4] [8;1;4;9]
-1
> compare [1;2;4] [1;2;3]
1
> compare [1;2;4] [1;2;4]
0
```

But when comparing strings the numbers can get larger than 1.

```ml
> compare "abf" "abc"
3
```

What does `compare` compare?

Comment: The contract is < 0, 0 and > 0. The values are irrelevant and it could have returned 7777 instead of 3. The case of the string it is probably the ordinal difference between the deciding characters. In any case, *don’t depend on the returned integer other than the relation to 0*.

Comment: The “contract” is better described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable.compareto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [F# Language specification](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf) provides a formal description of language elements. For the `compare` function see p. 173 "8.15.6 Behavior of Hash, =, and Compare", where the behavior is described in pseudocode to achieve the following objectives:

> - Ordinal comparison for strings
> - Structural comparison for arrays
> - Natural ordering for native integers (which do not support System.IComparable)

Structural comparison, an important concept in functional programming, does apply to tuples, lists, options, arrays, and user-defined record, union, and struct types whose constituent field types permit structural equality, hashing, and comparison.

For strings, the comparison relies on [`System.String.CompareOrdinal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareordinal), whose return values are described under the [`System.String.Compare`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare) method:

> Less than zero: strA precedes strB in the sort order.
>
> Zero: strA occurs in the same position as strB in the sort order.
>
> Greater than zero: strA follows strB in the sort order.